# How to turn off self-signed SSL certificate warning in Windows Live Mail?

Tags: windows-7, ssl-certificate, windows-live-mail

Every time I open Windows Live Mail 2012 it throws a security warning and won't connect until I press Yes:

[image: Screenshot]

It's a mail server with self-signed SSL certificate. How do I add exception permanently so that this warning would not appear anymore?

Comment: Look into importing the self-signed certificate into the client machine.

Comment: Download the certificate and place it on the user's certificate store

Comment: Guys could you write the steps to do that and post it as an answer?

Comment: Downloadng the certificate and adding it to local certificate store didn't help. Does it make a difference what directory it's added to in the certificate store?